Are fourier transforms a viable method to analyze data that isn't necessarily periodic?
I am looking at a dataset that is pulled from a test. This test occasionally produces periodic behavior in the data, but this is considered bad and I need to detect and flag it. The periodicity can also appear only briefly during the test.
It's work related, so I can't give specifics, however here's an example to illustrate what I mean. Imagine a pendulum at rest. Every once in a while, a gust of wind blows and causes it to start swinging infinitely until something stops it. (lets also pretend that the behavior of the swing changes based on the strength of the gust) If you print out its positional data, you'd have a lot of flat, with finite periods of periodic behavior.
Now, lets say I wanted to apply a Fourier transform to catch the periods of swinging and quantify it, (frequency, amplitude, etc) but I don't know beforehand when/where those periods are in the dataset - or even if there are any at all. Is this a viable approach? Is there a better method?

Are you familiar with the Short Time Fourier Transform?

I found the python function for it, I've been researching it, but am still kind of confused on it and how to implement it, particularly with the required "fs" and "hop" arguments.

What are you confused about?

I think I figured it out, fs appears to be the sampling rate that the data was gathered at. Hop still seems odd. However, I already have an open ticket on using that function here and am looking more for confirmation/guidance on if my approach is correct on this ticket.
